# Numbering bookmarks in R Markdown

Tags: numbering, r, bookmarks, markdown

I want to number the bookmarks in my PDF that I am creating with R Markdown.
When I add `- \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}` to the YAML I get the following error message:
`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.`
Is there a workaround or a better solution?

This is my full YAML:

```
---
title: "blabla"
author: "TobiSonne"
date: '`r paste("Stand:", format(Sys.Date(), "%d.%m.%Y"))`'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 1
classoption: landscape
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{float} 
  - \floatplacement{figure}{H}
  - \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  - \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
---
```

Comment: Maybe use the hypersetup approach. I am on q mobile phone right now and cannot provide better information

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Adding `- \hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered = true}` to my YAML worked!

Comment: Happy to help. I can later post a shot answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment to Answer :)

- I do not know YAML.
- I assumed that somehow the `hyperref` package is already loaded in your scenario/setting and therefore you cannot load the package again with your custom code.
- `hyperref` offers a command to add/modify the settings after the package is already loaded: The command is called `\hypersetup`.

Answer (score 1):

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
classoption: 
- bookmarksnumbered
---
 
# Foo

## Sub-foo

# Bah 

# Baz
```

**Edit**

I realized that there is one vote to delete this post,  but the answers show a correct way to pass to `hyperref` package the `bookmarksnumbered` and avoid the `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref`.

Moreover, IHMO this way is better for a Rmarkdown document that include LaTeX code directly in the header, as the main YAML header purpose is to be a friendly interface to the document settings without dealing, as far as possible, with code of the final format.

Moreover, this approach is also applicable to other option clashes of other packages as `xcolor`, which obviously cannot be fixed with `\hypersetup`.

As one can see in the screenshot, The MWE produces a PDF with bookmarks generated with LaTeX without any error. So, why should it be deleted? Please explain.

---

[image]

---